# open a URL in web browser from application with username and password

Tags: android

How to open an URL from my android application and pass the saved username and password that will fill in the website(like facebook) appropriate fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AIK, its possible for your custom webpage as you have its content to know where to pass the username and password but with facebook and gmail you can't do it.

You must have to integrate facebook sdk to implement such functionality. And there user can able to enter his/her username and password.

hope you got my point.

Enjoy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer("http://yoururl/yourpage.xxx?");
buffer.append("?username="+URLEncoder.encode("xxxxxxx"));
buffer.append("&pass="+URLEncoder.encode("xxxxxxxx"));
webView.loadUrl(buffer.toString());
```

then you can catch these querysting in your web page.

to login facebook look at this post http://talhakosen.com/2012/11/22/facebook-api-for-android/
which i wrote on my blog.

Comment: Will it pass username and password to facebook or gmail ?

Comment: You can catch it in your webpage, not in facebook. If you want to login facebook, you should look at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

Comment: I use the following code to open the browser Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);  is there a way to pass the username and password which is saved in my application along with the url

Comment: you can not do it with using ACTION_VIEW, http://talhakosen.com/2012/11/22/facebook-api-for-android/  look at my post